# how is it possible to match string like this in one regular expression in java

Tags: java, regex, email, hyperlink

My input String = "whatever text  href=\"http://somewhere.com?id=name@domain.com\" whatever text"

i need to match whole link http://somewhere.com?id=name@domain.com in group(1)

and also match email like name@domain.com in group(2) in one regex

now i use 2 matcher one for link and another for email like below

Matcher email = MAILS.matcher(string);
 Matcher href = LINKS.matcher(string);

the question is it is possible to combine it to one for efficiency.

thank for advance

Comment: Its kinda simple. If you start to get panicked about the characters that an `URL` can contain, try to guess what characters it **doesn't** (like whitespaces, but that would depend if your URL is encoded or not)

Answer (score 1):

It's very rough, but you could use it to start with:

```
/(http:\/\/[a-z]*\.(com)\?[a-z]+=[a-z]+@[a-z]+\.(com))/i
```

You could use http://rubular.com/ to test your expressions

Comment: Why would you use a Ruby webservice to test Java regexes?

Comment: why not? regex it's not java only

Answer (score 0):

```
href=\\"(http://[A-Za-z0-9\.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}\?id=([A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}))\\"
```

\1 is the link

\2 is the id (email address)

The link can be made up of letters, numbers, . -

The link top-level domain can be any 2,3,or 4 letter string.

The email address portion should be able to match 99% of all email addresses.

A great tutorial focusing on regex can be found at http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html